# error - c taking address of temporary

Tags: c++

I'm getting a error in the following piece of code

```
void setStyle(const ctlStyleBase* style)
{
  //do something
}

void create(const ctlStyleBase* style = 0)
{
      if(style == 0) setStyle(&ctlStyleGradient());  // error : taking address of temporary
      else setStyle(style);
}
```

I don't think this is wrong, because I only use it in setStyle, and it won't get destructed before setStyle returns.
Could some one tell me whether the code has some problems?

[compiler g++ 4.7.2]

Comment: pass const reference to avoid the error: `const ctlStyleBase& style`

Comment: It has a problem of taking address of a temporary (it's not more valid than `&(5+7)` -- did you expect it to work too?)

Comment: use a reference, looks like `ctlStyleGradient()` returns by value, and you can bind that temporary to a *const reference*, so change your signature to `void setStyle(const ctlStyleBase& style)` and call with `setStyle(ctlStyleGradient());`

Comment: Is the error a bit of a give away?

Comment: try this: `if(style == 0) { ctlStyleBase temp = ctlStyleGradient(); setStyle(&temp);} else setStyle(style);`

Comment: I would change setStyle to take a reference.

Comment: What's the prototype of the ctlStyleGradient() function ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, tough - it's a rule of the language that you cannot take the address of a temporary object. The reason for the rule is that there is basically never a good *reason* to do this.

In your example, `ctlStyleGradient()` returns some object of type `ctlStyleBase`. If you wanted to modify that object in the `setStyle` function (although you don't in this case), then as soon as you're done, the object ceases to exist, thus making the whole modification pointless.

Yes, you can contrive code where the operation has observable side effects, but that by itself would be very poor style. So, there's no deep technical reason why you shouldn't be able to take the address of a temporary, but the language decided not to let you do it because it's considered inappropriate.

But this doesn't seem what you're trying to do. Perhaps what you meant to do was for `ctlStyleGradient()` to return a pointer itself? Or, if you only need to *observe* a state and never change it, pass the state along by value or by const-reference.

Comment: The setStyle function probably does not modify anything (it takes a const*)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you simply cannot take the address of an rvalue expression. Your `ctlStyleGradient` returns a `ctlStyleBase` by value, copying it out of the function. This gives you a temporary and `ctlStyleGradient()` is an rvalue expression. You can't then do `&` on this expression.

If you don't need to modify the object that you pass to `setStyle`, then you can change it to take a `const` reference:

```
void setStyle(const ctlStyleBase& style)
{
  //do something
}

if(style == 0) setStyle(ctlStyleGradient());
```

If you do need to modify it, then you'll have to take a local copy of the `ctlStyleBase` object and pass that by value or reference:

```
void setStyle(ctlStyleBase style)
{
  //do something
}


if(style == 0) {
  ctlStyleBase styleCopy = ctlStyleGradient();
  setStyle(styleCopy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
void create(const ctlStyleBase* style = 0)
{
      if(style == 0)
      {
          ctlStyleGradient temp;
          setStyle(&temp);
      }
      else setStyle(style);
}
```

But, honestly, I would rework your code so you don't do this, passing pointers to local variables like this is risky business. Perhaps alter the `setStyle` call so that it checks for the null pointer?

Comment: yes, it really is a way to solve this problem, but it seems that the code is unsightly